# PHP - Get post data from Facebook page using only facebook graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

is there a way to get **Facebook** page the contents of an post using simple `php`.

i need to do that without The **Php-sdk** or the **Facebook API** only using the **Facebook Graph** and **Facebook app**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
/*xxxxclient_idxxx='your clientid'*/
/*xxxxxxclient_secretxxxx='your client_secret'*/
//Replace "YOUR-PAGE-NAME" with your page name.
$access_str = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxclient_idxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxclient_secretxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials');
$tokenarr = str_replace('"','',$access_str);
$tokenarray = explode(":",str_replace(',',':', $tokenarr));
var_dump($tokenarray);  //Request the public posts. 
$json_str = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR-PAGE-NAME/feed??fields=attachments&fields=attachments&access_token='.$tokenarray[1]);

//decode json string into array

$data = json_decode($json_str);

foreach ($data as $posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post){
    $postit = (array) json_decode(json_encode($post), True);
    foreach ($postit as $getit) {
    echo '<p>' .$getit['data'][0]['description'].'</p>';
    echo '<img src="'.$getit['data'][0]['media']['image']['src'].'" />';
    echo "</br>-----------</br>";
        }

    }
}

?>
```

This script get the status text and images